# Failed to resolve cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++

I tried compiling the below program with "g++ -std=c++11 -o w w.cpp" and geting the error " cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" ".
Tried compiling with g++ -Dstd=c++11 -o w w.cpp and getting the below set of errors:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream:40,
                 from w.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stringfwd.h:42: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘++’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stringfwd.h:42: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘++’ token
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/postypes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream:40,
                 from w.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cstddef:49: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘++’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cstddef:49: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘++’ token
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/postypes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream:40,
                 from w.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:65: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘++’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:65: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘++’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:139: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘++’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:139: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘++’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:245: error: ‘::wcstold’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:254: error: ‘::wcstoll’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:255: error: ‘::wcstoull’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:260: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘++’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cwchar:260: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘++’ token
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream:40,
                 from w.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/postypes.h:70: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘++’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/postypes.h:70: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘++’ token
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream:40,
                 from w.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected declaration before end of line

program- w.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int read_words(vector<string>& words, ifstream& in)
{
  int i = 0;
  while(!in.eof())
    in >> words[i++];
  return i-1;
}

int main()
{
  ifstream ifp("names");

  vector<string> w(500);
  int number_of_words = read_words(w, ifp);
  w.resize(number_of_words);

  for(auto it : w)
    cout << it << " ";
  cout << endl;

  map<string, string> wMap;

  for(int i = 0; i  <  number_of_words;) {
    wMap.insert(pair<string, string>(w[i], w[i+1]));
    i += 2;
  }

  cout << "wMap.size()=" << wMap.size() << endl;
  for(auto it = wMap.begin(); it != wMap.end(); it++)
    cout <<  it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
}
```

gcc Version:
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)

Please help me to sought out this issue.

Comment: Did you forget to add program?

Comment: The first gcc with C++11 feature complete is branch 4.8.1 from 2013. Don't expect with a 4.4 from 2009 to have everything from the iso c++ 2011.

Answer (score 4):

`-std=c++11` is only supported by GCC 4.7 and later. For other versions, you can use `std=c++0x` (available since GCC 4.3). See GCC’s overview on [‘C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC’](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) for more information about C++11 support in different GCC versions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-std=c++0x` for gcc versions lower than 4.7